# How can I use Ruby's net/ssh to establish a connection to a host in a target network?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to establish a connection to a host inside a target network using Ruby's net/ssh. If I were in bash, it would look something like this:

```
ssh $gateway_host -t ssh $target_host
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not much to be honest. I have managed to establish a normal ssh session to a target host, as well as reading and writing data. The documentation has been unhelpful thus far. I am willing to tinker around, just figured someone might have an obvious answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gw = Net::SSH::Gateway.new(gw_host, gw_user)
gw.ssh(server_host, server_user) do |ssh|
    ssh.exec!("do_stuff")
end
```

Comment: Nevermind, found it >_< I was looking under the net/ssh suite.